# Laravel 5.2 Entrust migrate error, cannot add foreign key constraints

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, entrust

I installed and configure the Laravel 5.2, its working fine, for `User ACL` I installed the `zizaco/entrust` package while running this command `php artisan migrate` (for creating `roles`, `permissions` table etc) getting following error

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table
>   `role_user` add constraint role_user_user_id_foreign foreign key
>   (`user_id`) references ``    (`id`) on delete cascade on update
>   cascade)
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add
>   foreign key constraint

What could be the reason ? am I missing something ? I followed the step wise guideline from entrust [site](https://packagist.org/packages/zizaco/entrust)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I fixed the issue, in entrust migration file, there was `users` table name missing. see following line

> $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on(**' '**)->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

So I changed to this,

> $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('**users**')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

I added the `users` table name, and issue is fixed.

**Reason, Why I got this issue?**

in `config/auth.php` file, there was not a `'table'=>'users'` key/pair mentioned in providers array, see below (this is default, means when fresh laravel is installed)

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
```

while `php artisan entrust:migration` command runs, it pulls the `users` table name from above providers array, if there is no table mentioned then in migration file, relationship sets empty like this.

> $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on(**''**)->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

So, add table in provider array like this.

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'table'=>'users'
    ],
```

after that run command for entrust migration `php artisan entrust:migration` this will generate the proper migration file.

Answer (score 2):

I get same error sometimes when I'm trying to add foreign keys in the same migration (same `Schema::create` block). If I'm creating migration where I'm creating new column:

```
Schema::create(...
    ...
    $table->integer('categories_id')->unsigned();
    ...
});
```

And then in the same file I'm setting this column as foreign key:

```
Schema::table('sub_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('categories_id')->references('id')->on('main_categories');
});
```

It works perfectly.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If U Use All Other Solution that given in GitHub or StackOverflow and not resolve your issue then delete users table from database admin panel and make some changes in the **users migration** file. Change the **bigIncrements('id');** to **Increment('id')**. 
**Or** 
Goto Database admin panel like if you use MySQL goto PHPmyadmin panel here goto database and then users here change the datatype of **id** from **bigint(20)** into **int(10).**